# How to style ButtonGroup with variant='text' in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to change the colour of my Buttons nested inside a ButtonGroup. I want to change the text colour as well as the "|" lines in between the buttons. I have tried overriding every class that I could find using the developer's console through `styled` but none of them had any effect.

```
const SortOptionButtonGroup = styled(ButtonGroup)({
  '& .MuiButtonGroup-root': { color: pageColor, borderColor: pageColor },
  '& .MuiButtonGroup-text': { color: pageColor, borderColor: pageColor },
});

const SortOptionButton = styled(Button)({
  '& .MuiButton-root': { color: pageColor, borderColor: pageColor },
  '& .MuiButton-text': { color: pageColor, borderColor: pageColor },
  '& .MuiButton-textPrimary': { color: pageColor, borderColor: pageColor },
  '& .MuiButton-sizeMedium': { color: pageColor, borderColor: pageColor },
  '& .MuiButton-textSizeMedium': { color: pageColor, borderColor: pageColor },
  '& .MuiButtonBase-root': { color: pageColor, borderColor: pageColor },
  '& .MuiButtonGroup-grouped': { color: pageColor, borderRight: pageColor },
  '& .MuiButtonGroup-groupedHorizontal ': { color: pageColor, borderColor: pageColor },
  '& .MuiButtonGroup-groupedText': { color: pageColor, borderColor: pageColor },
  '& .MuiButtonGroup-groupedTextHorizontal': { color: pageColor, borderColor: pageColor },
  '& .MuiButtonGroup-groupedTextPrimary': { color: pageColor, borderColor: pageColor },
});
```

I am using v5.4.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do it like so:

- use `.MuiButtonGroup-grouped` to control the style the **[ButtonGroup children](https://mui.com/api/button-group/)**, regardless of the variant. If you'd like to be more specific, you can use a class based on the current variant instead. For example,
  `.MuiButtonGroup-groupedText` when variant is text.
- use `not(:last-of-type)` [pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) to customize style of all but last buttons borders (i.e the buttonGroup dividers).

The final code look like this:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import ButtonGroup from "@mui/material/ButtonGroup";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const StyledButtonGroup = styled(ButtonGroup)({
  // change the text color for all buttons
  '& .MuiButtonGroup-grouped': {
    color: "green",
  },
  // change the button group dividers color
  '& .MuiButtonGroup-grouped:not(:last-of-type)': {
    borderColor: "red"
  }
});

export default function VariantButtonGroup() {
  return (
    <StyledButtonGroup variant="text">
      <Button>One</Button>
      <Button>Two</Button>
      <Button>Three</Button>
    </StyledButtonGroup>
  );
}
```

You can see  a demo of it [in this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-buttongroup-material-etbnl).

Answer (score 0):

You can change inner button styles (color, background-color, etc) directly through styled:

```
const StyledButton = styled(Button)({
  color: '#ff0000',
  backgroundColor: '#00ff00'
})
```

The divider line between buttons is implemented as buttons' border, so to change it, you should style button border inside ButtonGroup. You can do something like this:

```
const StyledButtonGroup = styled(ButtonGroup)({
  "& .MuiButtonGroup-grouped:not(:last-of-type)": {
    borderColor: "#ebc200"
  }
});
```

Here's an [example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/muibuttongroup-styles-m8xdt)